# How to disable the "grid line" option in Excel report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, xls

I have a jasper report with output in excel, I would like to **disable** the "*grid line*" option in excel for the background to be all white.

How I can do this in jasper report?

EDIT: The following examples worked for me !!

You set this property directly in your jrxml

**[`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines=false`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines)**, the default value is `true`

**jrxml example**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reputation" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true" uuid="a88bd694-4f90-41fc-84d0-002b90b2d73e">
     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines" value="false"/>
     ....
</jasperReport>
```

or if you are exporting from java set the [`SimpleXlsReportConfiguration.setShowGridLines(false)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/AbstractXlsReportConfiguration.html#setShowGridLines(java.lang.Boolean))

**java example**

```
JRXlsExporter exporterXls = new JRXlsExporter();
exporterXls.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporterXls.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("excelTest.xls")));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configXls = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configXls.setShowGridLines(false);
//set your additional settings
exporterXls.setConfiguration(configXls);
exporterXls.exportReport();
```

> **Note:** The code shows xls (since tagged xls) example but the same
>   property can be used for the `SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration` (xlsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set this property directly in your jrxml

**[`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines=false`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines)**, the default value is `true`

**jrxml example**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reputation" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true" uuid="a88bd694-4f90-41fc-84d0-002b90b2d73e">
     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines" value="false"/>
     ....
</jasperReport>
```

or if you are exporting from java set the [`SimpleXlsReportConfiguration.setShowGridLines(false)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/AbstractXlsReportConfiguration.html#setShowGridLines(java.lang.Boolean))

**java example**

```
JRXlsExporter exporterXls = new JRXlsExporter();
exporterXls.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporterXls.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("excelTest.xls")));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configXls = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configXls.setShowGridLines(false);
//set your additional settings
exporterXls.setConfiguration(configXls);
exporterXls.exportReport();
```

> **Note:** The code shows xls (since tagged xls) example but the same
>   property can be used for the `SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration` (xlsx)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: if you could help me with another question:
I have a report that needs to have an image printed only in the **last row** of the table of each page.
How can I create my **print when expression**?

Comment: @sergioBertolazo hmm you can probably not know that it's last row of table, before it's to late, try to rethink the report, for example use a groupFooter band (group on page) and put your image in that, or use negative coordinates in the pageFooter band.

Comment: thank you for your help, i can solve this problem using the resource "resetType=page"